# How to get into the Action and passed parameters based on the button click in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**UPDATE**
Ok, I got point that I move in wrong direction=) So, the Idea:

I have a table on my page (`View = Index.cshtml`):

```
<tbody id="SessionListBody">

<tr style="display: none;"> … </tr>
<tr>
    <td id="2" class="date"> … </td>
    <td> … </td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="/Home/MattersSession/2"> … </a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="3" class="date"> … </td>
    <td> … </td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="/Home/MattersSession/3"> … </a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="4" class="date"> … </td>
    <td> … </td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="/Home/MattersSession/4"> … </a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="5" class="date"> … </td>
    <td> … </td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="/Home/MattersSession/5"> … </a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="6" class="date"> … </td>
    <td> … </td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="/Home/MattersSession/6"> … </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Every row contains button. I need to get the `id` of the first `td` of the row when button was clicked and pass this `id` to my action:

```
public ActionResult MattersSession(int sessionPageID)
        {
            DBAccess dba = new DBAccess();
            DataTable dt = dba.GetSessionPage(sessionPageID);
            Session["SourceFileID"] = dt.Rows[0]["SourceFileID"];
            Session["SessionPageID"] = sessionPageID;

            // Generate Table and pass it to the View
            ViewData["MattersTable"] = dt.Rows[0]["MainTableBody"];
            ViewData["SummaryTable"] = dt.Rows[0]["SummaryBody"];

            return View("Matters");
        }
```

Now when I click links I'm getting this error:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'sessionPageID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult MattersSession(Int32)' in 'QuickbookUploadFromElite3e.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

But I need this parameter to call this method `DataTable dt = dba.GetSessionPage(sessionPageID);`, so if I will do this param optional, it's going to be comile error?

Comment: Try adding an argument to your error function `error: function (e) {` and alerting `e.message`?

Comment: is your method on the controller being hit and is the id being populated?

Comment: You need to change `dataType:json` to `dataType:html`

Comment: I would guess PSL is correct, unless your view returns json.

Comment: You are making an ajax call. It wont redirect to a view instead you will just get the view html. What do you mean by redirect to view anyways? If you want to redirect to another view why are you using ajax?

Comment: This view renders some tables from ViewData, I want to put data in the ViewData in my action based on the parameter that I sent from ajax and render this "Matters" view

Comment: Basically you want to redirect to another url showing your table data?. You use ajax generally if you want to update a partial view inside the same page without any redirection. Or is it that you want to update the view on the same page under some section?

Comment: You are getting the null parameter error because your routes are probably set up like `{controller}/{action}/{id}` so it assumes that anything in the 3rd segment will be bound by a parameter named `id`, but you have named your parameter in your action method `SessionPageId` so it cannot find the binding.

Comment: THANKS!!!! Exactly! =) Ough. MVC blow my mind=) Can you edit your answer, so I can accept it=) Thanks everybody for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to make a few assumptions in my answer. Please let me know if any of these assumptions are incorrect and I will adjust my answer:

1. You are using Bootstrap
2. These buttons are going to load a new page (essentially a GET request)
3. <strike>You are making your rows from a strongly-typed (IEnumerable) view</strike> You use ViewData

If all of these assumptions are true, I would solve it by using an anchor link and just give it the appearance of a button. Use the View's model to get the ID for each item.

```
@foreach(var item in ViewData["MattersTable"]){
<tr>
    <td id="@item.Id" class="date"> … </td>
    <td> … </td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="/myController/MattersSession/@item.Id"> "Button" Text </a>
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Furthermore, you are getting the null parameter error because your routes are probably set up like `{controller}/{action}/{id}` so it assumes that anything in the 3rd segment will be bound by a parameter named `id`, but you have named your parameter in your action method `SessionPageId` so it cannot find the binding.

Comment: I totally agree with this! Why use buttons when anchors are made just for that purpose? and using bootstrap classes it looks just like buttons...

Comment: See my edits. You are almost right except it is NOT a strongly-typed (IEnumerable) view

Comment: You already have the required information with the url parameter, but you need to change the parameter name from `sessionPageID` to `id`, the default routes that the parameter name would be `id`.

Comment: JOBG is right, i put same comment in your question. I've also adjusted my answer to use ViewData. But I try to never use ViewData, so the syntax might be wrong. (you should really try to use strongly typed views. It will make it easier on you in the long run)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your action method attributes, but I can guess it's because of missing [HttpPost]. Try to modify your code in this way:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MattersSession(int sessionPageID)
{   
    return View("Matters");
}
```

Another reason: you may have [ValidateAntiforgetyToken] attribute. If so, it won't work, because you're not passing antiforgery token with ajax.

Comment: The `HttpPost` attribute doesn't _allow_ post requests, it _restricts_ to post requests. Posting to an action without any http method restrictions will work fine.

Comment: [HttpPost] doesn't change anything. As I said I goes inside action, but instead of render "Matters" view for me it returns in error in ajax

Comment: @Bryuk Your view returns html and not json (I believe which is generally the case). So yo need to change dataType to html. Also see if you are getting it inside your action at all as well. Looking at your network console will give you more details regarding the issue.